# if else statement with set condition (SQL)

Tags: sql

just wondering, is there a reason why the below code doesn't work? I am trying to update 2 column values if they hit multiple criteria but I got an error that says 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' and 'Incorrect syntax near 'Total ' . Any help greatly appreciated!

```
update  [dbo].[wages table]
IF([criteria1]='AA1' and [criteria2]='50yrs and below' and [criteria3]= 'X<=50') 
set [Total ] = '0', [Employee ]='0' else
if ([criteria1]='AA1' and [criteria2]='50yrs and below' and [criteria3]= 'X<=50') 
set [Total ] = '10', [Employee ]='10' else
if ([criteria1]='AA1' and [criteria2]='50yrs and below' and [criteria3]= 'X<=50') 
set [Total ] = '20', [Employee ]='20' else
if ([criteria1]='AA1' and [criteria2]='50yrs and below' and [criteria3]= 'X<=50') 
set [Total ] = '30', [Employee ]='30' else
set [Total ] = 'NULL', [Employee ]='NULL'
```

Comment: Is the condition `if ([criteria1]='AA1' and [criteria2]='50yrs and below' and [criteria3]= 'X<=50') ` same for all?

Comment: What database platform are you using? SQL Server, Oracle etc.

Comment: Use CASE (expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are trying to do:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[wages table]
   SET [Total] = CASE [criteria3] WHEN 'X<=50' THEN '0' ELSE 'NULL' END,
   SET [Employee] = CASE [criteria3] WHEN = 'X<=50' THEN '0' ELSE 'NULL' END
WHERE [criteria1]='AA1' and [criteria2]='50yrs and below'
```

If `criteria1` and `criteria2` are same for all then you can check it in `WHERE` clause. I believe the difference is in `criteria3`.

Something like:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[wages table]
   SET [Total] = CASE [criteria3] WHEN 'X<=50' THEN '0' WHEN 'X<=40' THEN 1 WHEN 'X<=30' THEN 3 ELSE 'NULL' END,
   SET [Employee] = CASE [criteria3] WHEN 'X<=50' THEN '0' WHEN 'X<=40' THEN 1 WHEN 'X<=30' THEN 3 ELSE 'NULL' END
WHERE [criteria1]='AA1' and [criteria2]='50yrs and below'
```

Answer (score 2):

In `SQL` you can you `CASE` expressions for this type of statements:

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[wages table]
SET [Total] = CASE WHEN ([criteria1]='AA1' AND [criteria2]='50yrs and below' AND [criteria3]= 'X<=50')  THEN '0' 
                   WHEN ([criteria1]='AA1' AND [criteria2]='50yrs and below' AND [criteria3]= 'X<=50')  THEN '0' 
                   WHEN ([criteria1]='AA1' AND [criteria2]='50yrs and below' AND [criteria3]= 'X<=50')  THEN '0' 
                   ELSE NULL END,
    [Employee ] = CASE WHEN ([criteria1]='AA1' AND [criteria2]='50yrs and below' AND [criteria3]= 'X<=50')  THEN '0' 
                   WHEN ([criteria1]='AA1' AND [criteria2]='50yrs and below' AND [criteria3]= 'X<=50')  THEN '0' 
                   WHEN ([criteria1]='AA1' AND [criteria2]='50yrs and below' AND [criteria3]= 'X<=50')  THEN '0' 
                   ELSE NULL END
```

Besides, I can't see any difference in your conditions.

Comment: Can i set 2 values in one single line instead of duplicating the conditional statements again? My conditions are different in reality.

Comment: @Laughy, no you can not